# How does StreamCodec differ to Codec in Python?

Tags: python

In the Python 2 documentation, for [`codecs.Codec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codec-objects) it states, "Use `StreamCodec` for codecs which have to keep state in order to make encoding/decoding efficient".

However, `StreamCodec` is not documented within the `codecs` module, and nor does it appear anywhere else in the documentation.

How does `StreamCodec` differ to `Codec`? Is there any difference in the API or its guarantees, and are there any specific attributes where state should be stored?

Comment: It's a bug in the documentation. The class is StreamReader ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#streamreader-objects )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mistake in Python documentation. It should read StreamReader/StreamWriter.

Related bug in Python Bug Tracker is [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue12160)